# reconnect keyword argument on ClearDB default connection string causing errors with MySQLdb

Tags: python, django, heroku, cleardb

I uploaded a Django app to Heroku and than provision the cleardb add-on using these 3 commands from Heroku documentation:

```
heroku addons:create cleardb:ignite
heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true'
```

it seems to be O.K and the app is running (but without database).
now I try to run:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 61, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 274, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: 'reconnect' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Where does the problem comes from and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to remove "?reconnect=true" from the end of DATABASE_URL

Comment: Thanks, It works! what "?reconnect=true" means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove `?reconnect=true` from the end of DATABASE_URL

The parameters after the database are arguments to the MySQL server. In this case, it asks to reconnect if the connection is dropped. It looks like the MySQLdb package doesn't support that argument.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help! :) I have another question...It seems that if I wait a few seconds I am loosing the connection: "(2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')". But if I refresh the page then it works. Do you what should I do ? are there any other configurations I need to adjust? Appreciate your advice! :)

Comment: I have the exact same problem using MySQLdb and ClearDB. It appears that this is caused by dropping the `reconnect` keyword argument. I'll post here if I can figure out a way to set reconnect to True without triggering that error from MySQLdb

Comment: @TobyWeed I know this hasn't been written recently, but had you found any solution? I got a tip about using SQLAlchemy pooling, can you confirm this as well?

Comment: anyone knows a solution for this 2013 lost connection problem? I have been digging all over stackoverflow, heroku support etc and no luck