# How to connect to MySQL with a Flask app on Heroku using SQLAlchemy

Tags: heroku, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python, cleardb

On local machine, using a local MySQL database everything goes fine. Here is my app `__init__.py` file:

```
#rootfolder/__init__.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

ON_HEROKU = 'ON_HEROKU' in os.environ

if ON_HEROKU:
    DB_URL = os.environ.get('CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL')
else:
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    load_dotenv()
    DB_URL = os.getenv('MYSQL_URL')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DB_URL
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from projectname.Controller.root import root
from projectname.Controller.user_controller import user_routes # This imports Model too

app.register_blueprint(root)
app.register_blueprint(user_routes)

db.create_all()
```

The `user_routes` Blueprint imports the Model classes as well. I see the created tables in my local database, so the logic seems fine.

Printed out `'HELLO'` and the `DB_URL` inside the `if ON_HEROKU:` condition to check the url in the cloud:

```
if ON_HEROKU:
  DB_URL = os.environ.get('CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL')
  print('HELLO')
  print(DB_URL)
```

I can see them looking at heroku logs:

```
.
.
app[web.1]: HELLO
app[web.1]: mysql://*********:*******@us-cdbr-iron-east-05.cleardb.net/heroku_c52490fb3111cda?reconnect=true
.
.
```

Indeed, I have the installed ClearDB on heroku with that url as a config var:

[image]

I've also managed to connect to this heroku db using HeidiSQL and the url heroku created me. So everything must be at place.

Commenting out the `db.create_all()` function the deployed heroku app throws no error and I see the base json message following my root route. However, adding `db.create_all()` back I get the following log error:

```
app[web.1]:     db.create_all()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1033, in create_all
  .
  .
  .
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 118, in dbapi
app[web.1]:     return __import__("MySQLdb")
app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I had similar errors locally so I've tried to modify the URL heroku gave me with the `mysql+pymysql://` drivername and adding `PyMySQL==0.9.3` to my `requirements.txt` (I'm not sure if heroku checks that).

[image]

It was not enough the error is now:

```
app[web.1]:     db.create_all()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1033, in create_all
  .
  .
  .
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
app[web.1]:     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
app[web.1]: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reconnect'
```

My `Procfile` looks like this: `web gunicorn run:app`, as a `run.py` starts the whole application.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hey! This seems duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308110/reconnect-keyword-argument-on-cleardb-default-connection-string-causing-errors-w

If you remove `?reconnect=True`, does it fix the problem?

Comment: @JoseSalvatierra Yes, thank you! They are also talking another problem caused by removing the `?reconnect=true` parameter, which loses the created connection after some queries. I'm going to test this out, but it is working for now. :)

Comment: Yep, I believe you'll have to use SQLAlchemy's connection pooling in order to "fix" that problem. It can re-create broken connections without reconnecting them.

Comment: @JoseSalvatierra By the way, is there some explanation why `?reconnect=True` has to be deleted? My connection truly has now reconnection issues, so this feels like throwing away a quite reasonable feature. Why SQLAlchemy connection pooling is a better idea than implementing the usage of this parameter?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package, but it seems MySQLdb doesn't support the argument.