# pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

Tags: python, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy, pymysql, cleardb

I had problems connecting to the heroku ClearDB with my flask-restful application, using SQLAlchemy with my given `DB_URI`:

```
mysql+pymysql://username:password@remote-hostname-xx.cleardb.net/heroku_c52490fb3111cda?reconnect=true
```

And this was the error:

```
app[web.1]:     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
app[web.1]: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reconnect'
```

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45309839/6560773) was to remove the `?reconnect=true` parameter. But there where also [warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308110/reconnect-keyword-argument-on-cleardb-default-connection-string-causing-errors-w#comment77590162_45309839) that this could lead to connection losing issues, and indeed, it instantly happened to me as well:

```
2019-11-01T11:00:28.244117+00:00 app[web.1]:     CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
2019-11-01T11:00:28.244119+00:00 app[web.1]: pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
2019-11-01T11:00:28.244122+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-11-01T11:00:28.244124+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    .
    .
    .
2019-11-01T11:00:28.244267+00:00 app[web.1]:     CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
2019-11-01T11:00:28.244268+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
2019-11-01T11:00:28.24427+00:00 app[web.1]: [SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.email AS users_email, users.password AS users_password, users.`admin` AS users_admin 
2019-11-01T11:00:28.244272+00:00 app[web.1]: FROM users]
2019-11-01T11:00:28.244349+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
2019-11-01T11:00:28.245066+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.155.176 - - [01/Nov/2019:11:00:28 +0000] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "-"
```

For the first try I get every time a `500: internal server error`. The second try is usually sending back the `200: ok` code, but this behaviour is naturally breaking the service of my API.

Checking the logs, the error is clear:

```
(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

Now, I've also got a [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488537/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-a-flask-app-on-heroku-using-sqlalchemy#comment103309171_58488537) to use SQLAlchemy connection pooling to fix the issue.

**My question is:** How could I resolve this with SQLAlchemy pooling or should I even really use that to fix this reconnection error?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm having the same issue as well. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonLogsdon
Hey Jason, unfortunately not yet. Maybe the solution is [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look through there. Seems like a pretty big issue considering it's the only real mysql db heroku recommends for python.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the only work around I could find for this by talking to the ClearDB people is to add in the pessimistic ping when creating the engine.  For my initialization I now use:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.pool import QueuePool
db = SQLAlchemy(engine_options={"pool_size": 10, "poolclass":QueuePool, "pool_pre_ping":True})
```

It's obviously not an ideal solution since it pings the DB every time before you do a query. After these discussions I don't know if it's even possible to use mysql with Flask on heroku in a semi-optimized manner, especially using their "recommended" database provider.

I'm going to roll with this for now since I don't think my app will be query heavy, and I'm in early stages of development. Long term I may just end up switching off of Heroku entirely if I start to run into longer term issues from this.

Comment: Wow, I'm very grateful for you to provide your findings! Unfortunately I don't have the time to work on the actual project which induced the question, but gonna get back to it in a month. I was also just thinking today about leaving heroku for something more suitable. I'd be very interested in any possible option you may find for the time being :)

Comment: Okay, I'm back with the flask project again. I'm a bit rusty in my head how I left things, but you say pinging the DB every time worked, right? Yeah, it sounds a bit of an overkill, but have you got any slowing-down in time because of this? Also I have to ask if you've left Heroku to find something more suitable for a Flask + MySQL stack. I'm staying for Heroku at the moment just to develop further my backend. Thanks for sharing any information Jason :)

Comment: Yup, doing the "pool_pre_ping" has worked fine, no more connection errors.  My app isn't query heavy (and I hope to reduce it even more via caching later) so I haven't noticed any slowdown, though I'm still in development and not in front of a decent amount of users.

Comment: Sorry, also still on Heroku. The baked in ssl is enough to let me stay until the dbs become a pain point.